# PyArcade (Pyglet) python3 Help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyglet, arcade

Python 3.8.1

using python-arcade and linux manjaro os

This project is a multiplayer game built with python arcade

I get these errors while running :

```
class Client(arcade.Window):

    def __init__(
        self, 
        width: int, 
        height: int, 
        title: str = 'Immortals'
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(width, height, title=title)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iddos/Documents/Github/Python/immortals/immortals/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    main(**config['resolution'])
  File "/home/iddos/Documents/Github/Python/immortals/immortals/main.py", line 20, in main
    window = Immortals(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iddos/Documents/Github/Python/immortals/immortals/core/client.py", line 40, in __init__
    super().__init__(width, height, title=title)
  File "/home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcade/application.py", line 70, in __init__
    super().__init__(width=width, height=height, caption=title,
  File "/home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 171, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 642, in __init__
    self._create()
  File "/home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcade/application.py", line 469, in _create
    super()._create()
  File "/home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 352, in _create
    self.set_caption(self._caption)
  File "/home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcade/application.py", line 481, in set_caption
    super().set_caption(caption)
  File "/home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 511, in set_caption
    self._set_text_property('_NET_WM_NAME', caption)
  File "/home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 785, in _set_text_property
    raise XlibException('Could not create UTF8 text property')
pyglet.window.xlib.XlibException: Could not create UTF8 text property
```

And also this ffmpeg not found error, altough ffmpeg is in /usr/bin/ffmpeg

```
Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location: /home/iddos/.local/share/virtualenvs/immortals-SS7Euna6/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavfilter.so.7.
```

I would love to get some help from you guys since i didn't find a solution for this yet.

you can contact me on discord also - F4zi.#1107

Comment: Can you share a [mcve], or at least a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `pyglet.window.xlib.XlibException: Could not create UTF8 text property` as your locales are not correctly configured. This error comes from the LANG property in the locale.

this can be solved by

in your terminal

1. write `LANG=en_US`
2. Run your python code from the terminal

another solution is to configure the locale for your code by adding this piece of code in the starting of your code(before everything)

```
import os
os.environ['LANG']='en_US'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue as follows.

**1.Give the commands as follows.**

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

**2.Select the following in the scrolling menu**

```
en_US.UTF-8
```

**3.Confirm the command**

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

**4.reboot**

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Cheers!